# Error trying to convert excel sheet to pdf with xlwings

Tags: python, excel, pdf, xlwings

I have been trying to convert an excel sheet to a pdf using xlwings. I got it to work but I cannot update all links automatically without getting this error. I need the sheet to update without prompting the user to update. Anyone know how to fix this problem without running into an error. This is my code:

```
def create_report(name):
    if len(name) > 30:
        name = name[0:30]
    wb = xw.Book("Individual Supplier Report Cards.xlsx", update_links = all)
    sheet = wb.sheets[name]
    current_work_dir = os.getcwd()
    pdf_path = os.path.join(current_work_dir, "Report Card.pdf")
    sheet.api.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, pdf_path)
    os.startfile(pdf_path)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(0, LCID, 2, (9, 0), ((12, 1),),Index
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)
```

Edit:

The conversion to a PDF works but when it from my email function i get the same error. Anyone know what the problem is here? Here is my code:

```
def send_email(contact_list):
    for email, name in contact_list.items():
        if email == "[no contact]":
            continue
        msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative") 
        msg['From']= "xxxx"
        msg['To']= email
        msg['Subject']= "xxxx"
        message = open("Message template.txt", "r")
        str1 = ""
        for line in message:
            str1 = str1 + line
        message.close()
        message1 = MIMEText(str1)
        msg.attach(message1)
        create_report(name)
        pdfname = "Report Card.pdf"
        binary_pdf = open(pdfname, 'rb')
        payload = MIMEBase('application', 'octate-stream', Name=pdfname)
        payload.set_payload((binary_pdf).read())
        binary_pdf.close()
        encoders.encode_base64(payload)
        payload.add_header('Content-Decomposition', 'attachment', filename=pdfname)
        msg.attach(payload)
        s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host='smtp.gmail.com')
        s.login("xxx", "xxx")
        s.send_message(msg)
        s.quit
    del msg
```

Comment: Have you seen `sheet.to_pdf()`? See: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Sheet.to_pdf

Comment: just changed it to .to_pdf(), the conversion to a pdf works, but when I call it from another function it does not, I'll post the other function